# Gstreamer error in saving grayscale image with OpenCV VideoWriter

Tags: python, opencv, gstreamer

I might be missing something very obvious, but I can't seem to make this work.
I am reading frames from a grayscale camera which then I want to encode to H265 through gstreamer in OpenCV VideoWriter.

This is my gstreamer pipeline:

```
gst_out =('appsrc caps=video/x-raw,format=GRAY8,width=1280,height=800,framerate=30/1 ! '
    'videoconvert ! omxh265enc ! video/x-h265, stream-format=byte-stream ! '
    'h265parse ! filesink location=test.h265 ')

writer= cv2.VideoWriter(gst_out, cv2.CAP_GSTREAMER, 0, 30, (1280, 800), True)
```

but when I try to write frames in it I get the error

```
[ WARN:0] global /home/nvidia/host/build_opencv/nv_opencv/modules/videoio/src/cap_gstreamer.cpp (1629) writeFrame OpenCV | GStreamer warning: cvWriteFrame() needs images with depth = IPL_DEPTH_8U and nChannels = 3.
```

which I don't understand as it should be accepting the GRAY8 format, and I have verified that the frame as only one channel. If I convert the frame to BGR it works but that's not what I want as I only need to save the grayscale image and I also don't understand why it would accept the BGR frame when I specified GRAY8 in the pipeline.

Any help would be very much appreciated.

Comment: If you intend to create a grayscale video, then why are you constructing `cv2.VideoWriter` with the `isColor` argument set to `True`?

Comment: Oh my god, you're right! I knew I was making some silly mistake somewhere, I feel very stupid now. Thanks so much!

Comment: No worries, it happens :)

Comment: I think that @DanMašek should write this as an answer, and the OP should accept it :-)

Comment: @JonasVautherin Go for it, if you fell like it. I'm busy, and not very motivated to do that. ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are building your [`cv::VideoWriter`](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4.15/dd/d9e/classcv_1_1VideoWriter.html) with `isColor` set to `true`:

```
VideoWriter (const String &filename, int fourcc, double fps, Size frameSize, bool isColor=true)
```

This is why OpenCV expects a color image (with 3 channels) instead of grayscale.

(Note: this was discussed in the comments, I'm just writing it as an answer for the sake of closing the question)

Comment: Thank you for writing as an answer! I accepted it as you suggested :)